# Double Constructor Code Blocks, Static code block in Java

Tags: java, class, static, constructor, double

I stumbled upon this block of java code that seems to defy the syntax rules:

```
1. public class Sequence { 
2.     Sequence() { System.out.print("c "); } 
3.     { System.out.print("y "); } 
4.     public static void main(String[] args) { 
5.         new Sequence().go(); 
6.     } 
7.     void go() { System.out.print("g "); } 
8.     static { System.out.print("x "); } 
9. }
```

With reference to line 3, how could an independent block of code be opened like that?
I tested it and it worked. However, the logic flows in reverse: y will be printed before c.

Also, with reference to line 8, I am not sure what this block is trying to do. It seems like  a class declaration. In this case, shouldn't the static keyword be followed by a class name?

Could someone please clarify my doubts? Thank you.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the correct page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in line number 8 is called static initialization block. Where as the code in line 3 is called non-static initialization block.

static initialization blocks gets executed first. If  there are multiple static initialization blocks, they get executed in the order of appearance. The content of the non static initializer block(or simply initializer block) gets copied into the content of every constructor.

Comment: Worth pointing out that excessive use of either of these is likely a code smell.  Not that they don't have totally valid uses, just be judicious!

Comment: Thanks! All of your explanation were so helpful!